# How to send a time-limited coupon code to new subscribers?

Tags: magento2, coupon, mailchimp

I'm using Mailchimp for newsletter signups. I'm looking for a way to automatically send a coupon code to my new subscribers. I want the coupon to expire after 3 days.
Is there any extension that could help me achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Personal Discount](https://personaldiscount.io/?ref=se) solves exactly this problem.

You can set up an automation to generate unique coupon codes for people who sign up for your newsletter.

There's is an option to specify expiration date in days, counted from the moment when a new subscriber appeared.

[image: Personal Discount Automation Screenshot]

Then you can send the coupon from Mailchimp. Just include the merge tag `*|COUPON|*` in your email template.

[image: Mailchimp welcome email template with coupon merge tag]

*Disclosure: I'm a co-founder of Personal Discount*